# iOS Device is not Connecting to Internet in Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, xcode9.1

My iOS project is running but getting no internet access in this project, In Safari browser internet is fine, but only in the project i am unable to access internet.

- xcode project not connect to internet , already access internet in safari.
- Safari Internet access done,
- Project login is not working internet access error xcode 9.1.

[video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aNamn_Nh_rCJH7iyKQHYO2LgxAW325UK/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: what error? show your log. does your endpoint is http or https? which library you are using?

Comment: see above link this video.

Comment: xcode peoject not connect to internet , already access internet in safari.

Comment: did you check the `App Transport Sercurity`?

Comment: We didn't get enough details by viewing the video. You didn't show us the **error/log/endpoint link(http or https)**. we can't help you if you are not providing any details.

Comment: https working , i know App Transport Secutity

Comment: i have only problem in not connect internet

Comment: safari access to internet but app not access internet

Comment: see . link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1amZBhWNiU9n9jDoEYE-afXFLKRy-Mx4z

Comment: @VishalVaghasiya did u checked my answer, is that worked for you ?

Answer (score 2):

iOS devices should be connected same wifi networks and checked for connect via network under devices and simulators.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZBA0.png)

Comment: i have old version 10 so not connect to wifi

Comment: it's not possible for iOS 10 devices.

Comment: i know not possible

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. But this is the way to connect iOS Device with Xcode for Wireless debugging. The questionnaire asked for internet is not connected message show when he's trying to call API.

Comment: and please check yes for  "Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content" .  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
  <false/>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the API's / http request / the url you are using. And the network (wifi / mobile data) you are using to make the login request.

http request / the login url you are using may require your company's authorized wifi, to get response from that login request. I also faced the same issue when using a public wifi of my company, then informed this issue to the network team and backend team, then they gave access for some other authorized wifi, then i got the response successfully.

So discuss with your network team and the backend team.

And check the login url is working fine in Postman. It is an application used to check the API's / url's by the backend team are working fine. In that you just need to put the url and the parameters required.

Comment: i don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Are you in China? You may go to settings and choose Network, and then find your app in list. So you can change the net setting for your app.

Comment: i am Indian, give me internet settings. but safari working done.

Comment: only issue is project after run.

Comment: You could use `comment` feature in order to ask questions. @user2027712